# Path not found default redirect to root. How to do 404 routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

According to this article it should be fairly easy to make an 404 page:
https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/react-router-not-found-component

However in my enviroment this does not work. Below navigates to "/" if an invalid route are given?

```
const Main = () => (
  <div>
    <main>
      <Switch> 
        <Route path="/page2" component={Page2} />
        <AzureAD provider={authProvider} forceLogin={true}>
          <Route path="/page1/:token?" component={Page1} /> 
          <Route path="/tokenfail" component={TokenFailPage} />
          <Route path="/complete" component={CompletedPage} /> 
          <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        </AzureAD>
        <Route component={Page2} />
      </Switch>       
    </main>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to club both [Alfonso Tienda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63249837/13907595) and [Antonio Erdeljac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63249832/13907595) answers posted,

Keep the `exact` for `Home` and add a wildcard (*) for `404` paths (Remember to keep the `wildcard` route as last one)

```
...
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
...

<Route path="*" exact component={My404Component} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `<Route path="*" exact component={NotFoundComponent} />` to handle not found routes.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think this route:

```html
          <Route path="/" component={Home} />
```

is getting the 404.

Try with exact:

```
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
```